# Como salvar localmente dados retornados de uma API em um arquivo JSON?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, json

Estou fazendo uma requisição `HTTP` para receber dados, após receber os mesmos, eu necessito armazenar localmente em um arquivo `JSON`.

- Como posso criar e transferir estes dados para o arquivo `.json`?

**Requisição** `HTTP` **:**

```
const request = require('request');

request('url', (error, response, body) => {
    const parsedWeather = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**O navegador não pode manipular nada do seu sistema operacional, tudo que está disponível para a utilização é o que o navegador já permite.**

Se você deseja manipular dados de forma persistente em arquivos como por exemplo o `JSON`, deve ser utilizado um servidor! Para você uma opção seria o `NodeJS`, já que você utiliza o `Javascript`, utilizando o `NodeJS` você consegue manipular os arquivos com a biblioteca `fs` e utilizar o `CRUD`.

Mas não fique desanimado, caso não queira por alguma motivo utilizar um servidor (backend), você pode utilizar outras opções como:

- **1)** Armazenamento local com `LocalStorage` e/ou `SessionStorage`.
- **2)** Utilizar um `BaaS` (backend as a service), que possui um banco de dados `NoSQL` em tempo real, um exemplo já que utiliza `Javascript` é o `Firebase`!